# Screenshot in Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I want to take screenshot of each visited page by using selenium webdriver? 
i used this code:

```
try{

     File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
     FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot,new File("C:\\Users\\udit\\Desktop\\screenshot.jpeg"));
 }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("Failure to take screenshot "+e);
```

Comment: please provide more information about the problem you're facing?

Comment: Hi rupesh, i want to know that each time i have to put dis code to take screenshot.

Comment: I would say to avoid this you can create one class with method performing  action to take screen shot. Just call that method instead rewriting the screen shot code again.

Comment: Just take the code you have and put it in a function that takes the file path as a String parameter and call that function each time you are on a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it will work for you.

```
try{

                 File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                 String screenshotPath= "C:\\Users\\udit\\Desktop\\screenshot.jpeg";
                 FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot,new File(screenshotPath));
             }catch(Exception e){
                   System.out.println("Failure to take screenshot "+e);
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if still facing the problem?

Comment: How is this supposed to solve his problem? You took his exact code and put the path as a separate variable.

Comment: Because I have faced the same problem. It shows error in "FileUtils.copyFile", but when I took the path in a separate variable then its works fine.

Comment: There is no difference between the two. I just tried the exact code and it works fine.

Comment: Dear! there is no problem in the posted code. But sometimes it shows error in FileUtils.copyFile. It may be because of older verison of java.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you need to take multi-screen shot .. Try with following link
https://github.com/Pavan-and-Vikas-Utilities/MultiScreenShot